# Flutter PageView and FutureBuild Keeps loading from api every time i access the page

Tags: flutter, dart

i am facing an issue with Pageview and Futurebuild, that every-time i switch between first page and second page the page will be rebuilt again...it will call new data from API even if there is nothing new...anyone can help me in this

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 
  PageController pageController = PageController(keepPage: false);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();    
    }   
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final homePage = HomeProjects(pageController: pageController);
    final portfolioPage = Portfolio(pageController: pageController);


    return Scaffold(
      body: ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: MyBehavior(),
        child: PageView(reverse: true, controller: pageController,

            //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              homePage,
              portfolioPage,
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only making HTTP calls inside your pages that's a desired outcome. You'll need to cache the responses to avoid repeated network calls.

Moving api calls to `initState` is not something I would personally do - the data fetched on first page creation may become outdated without you knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you build your pages every time build is called.

If you don't want that, move the lines that actually build the pages to a time and place where they will be called only once. `initState` might be a good place.

Comment: tried that but no success, i have moved this line to initstate(),  homePage = HomeProjects(pageController: pageController);....but no success